# Webpack Encore can not find installed dependency Spectrum-colorpicker2

Tags: javascript, webpack, color-picker, webpack-encore, symfony-4.4

### Intro

I would like to use color picker in my project.

My choice stopped on `spectrum-colorpicker2` because of modern look and features.

- [Documentation site](https://seballot.github.io/spectrum/);
- [Code on github](https://github.com/seballot/spectrum);
- [YarnPKG package](https://yarnpkg.com/package/spectrum-colorpicker2).

I am using `Symfony v4.4` with `Webpack Encore` bundle.

For JS packages i use `YarnPKG`.

### Problem

Both `import` and `require` results in the same error.

### The error

```
[..]
PS D:\DEV\project> yarn encore dev
yarn run v1.22.4
$ D:\DEV\project\node_modules\.bin\encore dev
Running webpack ...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors

This dependency was not found:

* spectrum-colorpicker2 in ./assets/js/file_type_color.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save spectrum-colorpicker2
[..]
```

### Code 1

```
'use strict';

// loads the jquery package from node_modules
import $ from 'jquery';
var spectrum = require('spectrum-colorpicker2');
require('spectrum-colorpicker2/dist/spectrum.min.css');

$(function()
{
    $('#assign_color').spectrum({
        type: "component",
        showAlpha: "false"
    });
});
```

### Code 2

```
'use strict';

// loads the jquery package from node_modules
import $ from 'jquery';
import spectrum from 'spectrum-colorpicker2';
import 'spectrum-colorpicker2/dist/spectrum.min.css';

$(function()
{
    $('#assign_color').spectrum({
        type: "component",
        showAlpha: "false"
    });
});
```

### I tried

I tried adding and removing package multiple times, but result is the same.

```
yarn add spectrum-colorpicker2
yarn remove spectrum-colorpicker2
```

### Install log

```
[..]
PS D:\DEV\project> yarn add spectrum-colorpicker2
yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "node-notifier@6.0.0" is incompatible with requested version "node-notifier@^5.1.2"
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > sass-loader@7.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ spectrum-colorpicker2@2.0.0
info All dependencies
└─ spectrum-colorpicker2@2.0.0
Done in 5.22s.
[..]
```

### Wrap

If i made an error please correct me.
Please advise me on this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that downloaded package `spectrum-colorpicker2` is not formatted correctly!

It has `dist` folder inside of another `dist` folder.

As a result `Webpack` can not find required files.

Solution is: to include JavaScript file directly:

```
var spectrum = require('spectrum-colorpicker2/dist/spectrum.min.js');
```